# Уменьшить количество символов в теге определенного класса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Работая с таблицей, я наткнулся на одну проблему, внтури данной таблицы находятся такие данные как:

1. Id элемента
2. Имя объекта
3. Тип объекта
4. Координаты объекта

В 4 пункте, где записаны координаты объекта, координаты слишком длинные, моя задача сделать так чтобы эту длину укоротить:

Вот и сама данная таблица:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Coordinates</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>16</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint1
    </td>
    <td>
      Parking
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.381272280500674</span> : <span class="substring">49.842752143408234</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>17</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint2
    </td>
    <td>
      Bankomat
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.382694313910996</span> : <span class="substring">49.84732262756961</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>18</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint3
    </td>
    <td>
      Bank
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.379703105349265</span> : <span class="substring">49.84206549790042</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как вы можете заметить, то что координаты длинные, и нужно уменьшить их длину.

Я с помощью jQuery написал скрипт

```
$(".substring").substring(0,9);
```

Данный код не работает, или я делаю что-то не так.
Прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор возвращает массив элментов DOM, соответствующих селектору. Естественно, метода substring у этого массива нет. Необходимо перебрать элементы коллекции и изменить текст каждого из них. Для первого можно использовать [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), а для второго [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$('.substring').each(function() {
 $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 9));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Coordinates</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>16</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint1
    </td>
    <td>
      Parking
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.381272280500674</span> : <span class="substring">49.842752143408234</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>17</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint2
    </td>
    <td>
      Bankomat
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.382694313910996</span> : <span class="substring">49.84732262756961</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>18</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint3
    </td>
    <td>
      Bank
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.379703105349265</span> : <span class="substring">49.84206549790042</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Воуу) Спасибо :))))

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, спасибо тут принято выражать плюсуя рейтингу и принятием верного ответа (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: @Other 10 минут должно пройти)

Comment: [перегрузка позволяющая избавиться от прямого вызова each и двойного оборачивания `this` Для взятия текста](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

Comment: @Grundy шикарно!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант соседнего ответа, с использованием только [метода `text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```js
$('.substring').text(function(index, oldText) {
  return oldText.substring(0, 9);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Coordinates</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>16</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint1
    </td>
    <td>
      Parking
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.381272280500674</span> : <span class="substring">49.842752143408234</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>17</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      Kenan
    </td>
    <td>
      Bankomat
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.382694313910996</span> : <span class="substring">49.84732262756961</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>18</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint3
    </td>
    <td>
      Bank
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.379703105349265</span> : <span class="substring">49.84206549790042</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Кроме того, можно попробовать решить без js, используя только css.

```css
.substring {
  max-width: 68px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Coordinates</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>16</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint1
    </td>
    <td>
      Parking
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.381272280500674</span> : <span class="substring">49.842752143408234</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>17</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      Kenan
    </td>
    <td>
      Bankomat
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.382694313910996</span> : <span class="substring">49.84732262756961</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <b><i>18</i></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      TestPoint3
    </td>
    <td>
      Bank
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="substring">40.379703105349265</span> : <span class="substring">49.84206549790042</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: из первого кода, что там за index и oldtext??

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, это параметры, они в справке по ссылке описаны: index - индекс текущего выбранного элемента к которому применяется функция, `oldText` - это текущее значение свойства, в данном случае текста

Comment: Аааа теперь понятно) Вот реализация с помощью css прикольная, не думал что такое возможно тоже)

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, в css реализации все зависит от ширины текста. Тут просто максимальная ширина выставляется и все остальное просто не видно. Для другого набора цифр / шрифта скорее всего придется использовать другой размер. Тут лучше использовать моноширинный шрифт, чтобы ширина элемента зависела только от количества цифр, а не от самих цифр